# Unable to execute selenium testng code ( FileNotFoundException)

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, selenium

I have written dataprovider, testobjects and testcase classes and when i try to run getting the below error in eclipse

I have dragged and dropped the excel sheet, ie and chrome drivers in the path src/test/resources. Please let me know is this the correct way of adding the files to resources in eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\Selenium%20Docs\Selenium%20Setup\SeleniumLearning\target\test-classes\rediff_book_login.xls (The system cannot find the path specified)

    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)

    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)

    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)

    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)

    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)

    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)

    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)

    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)

    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)

    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)

    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)

    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)

    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)

    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)

    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)

    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)

    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)

    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)

    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)

    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)

    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the above provided solution or keep your file "`rediff_book_login.xls`" at the location "`G:\Selenium%20Docs\Selenium%20Setup\SeleniumLearning\target\test-classes\`"

Try code something like:

```
String filepath= "G:\\Selenium Docs\\Selenium Setup\\SeleniumLearning\\target\\test-classes\\rediff_book_login.xls"; FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
```

Or also you can try:

```
String filepath= "G:\\Selenium Docs\\Selenium Setup\\SeleniumLearning\\target\\test-classes\\rediff_book_login.xls"; FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filepath);
```

Comment: when i opened the path as you suggested the file 'rediff_book_login.xls' was already there.. Is there any other way to solve this

Comment: Try code something like:

String filepath= "G:\\Selenium Docs\\Selenium Setup\\SeleniumLearning\\target\\test-classes\\rediff_book_login.xls";
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));

Comment: Or also you can try:

String filepath= "G:\\Selenium Docs\\Selenium Setup\\SeleniumLearning\\target\\test-classes\\rediff_book_login.xls";
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filepath);

Answer (score 0):

Well if your Excel file resides in classpath, just load it via

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/rediff_book_login.xls");
```

... in the test case the slash above marks the directory src/test/resources.

If this does not help, please provide a code snippet, which shows us your file loading implementation.

Comment: I have used the following way for file loading : //Get the path of the file
  String filePath = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("rediff_book_login.xls").getFile();
  
  //Get the file
  File file = new File(filePath);
  
  //File input stream
  
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);                                                    //Work book
  HSSFWorkbook wb =  new HSSFWorkbook (fis)  -- Please let me know is there any wrong in this .

Comment: For the creation of the file object use my answer above or this way: new File(<YourCurrentClass>.class..getResourceAsStream("/rediff_book_login.xls").getFile());
The rest in your comment is exactly the way that I also chose, except that I use XSSFWorkbook for an xlsx document, but that does not matter here.

Comment: Doing it like you described with "ClassLoader.getSystemResource("rediff_book_login.xls").getFile();" is of course also ok but as you stated correctly, then you do not need the leading slash.